# When you install Gnome, do you still have access to Ubuntu standard desktop?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, gui

I recently installed gnome-fallback-session because it is a lot like ubuntu classic for 11.10 - my question is, am I able to go back to using the standard Ubuntu GUI that came out of box as well as gnome? or am I permanently stuck with Gnome?

Comment: GNOME is already installed!

Answer (score 1):

Unity, Gnome Shell and Gnome Fallback Sesion are just different GUIs for the Gnome3 desktop. You can choose at login which one you want to use by clicking on the "gears" symbol.

Comment: How about KDE? for some reason my computer gets a bit hot due to processes in the background - this only started happening with 11.10 - any GUI I can install that is less of a resource hog? it seems Gnome, Unity, etc may be the reason behind it.  What all GUIs am I able to install and use without having to redo Ubuntu all over again (because that's a pain..)

Answer (score 0):

### Yes

You can switch between them at the login screen by selecting the little gear icon.

If you dont have your login screen enabled it means your system is set to auto login.  You will need to enable this setting in

> System setting>>User Accounts and selecting
>
> User Password required